# bitset not setting the right value

Tags: c++, bit

bitset is not setting the right value when I print it

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<16> b = 01010;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

1010 in binary is 1111110010 yet it is printing 0000001000001000

Comment: `01010` is an *octal* literal...

Comment: Just a tip: when you're not getting the results you expect, look at the input and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: If you're going to blame something, blame the standard libraries last...

Comment: If I got a dollar for every question one SO that said something like "function x has a bug"… Paraphrasing what Pete and Monkey said: 99 times out of 100 it is user error, not a bug.

Comment: @Floris This is mostly why we are here. We are not here to find bugs in libraries or compilers but to help people with how to use them.

Comment: @Caesar - agreed. I was commenting on the fact that people often think that the function has a bug (at least that's how they phrase their question) - when usually it is their error. It's the way they ask the question, not the fact that they ask the question. This would be a pretty quiet forum if the only questions that came up were actual bugs in php, linux, java, etc libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you place a 0 in front of your number and so it is being read as if it was octal value. Remove the 0 and everything should work.